# Enable Disabled Button if Input is not empty

Tags: javascript

I have one simple form which have two fields called first name with id fname and email field with email. I have submit button with id called submit-btn.
I have disabled submit button using javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("submit-btn").disabled = true;
```

Now I am looking for allow submit if both of my fields are filled.

My full javascript is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
   document.getElementById("submit-btn").disabled = true;

   document.getElementById("submit-btn").onclick = function(){
   window.open("https://google.com",'_blank');
}
  
</script>
```

I am learning javascript and does not know how I can do it. Let me know if someone here can help me for same.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id propose something like this

1. Use a block, which encapsulates the names of variables and functions inside the [block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)
2. [Make small functions, which do just one thing](https://medium.com/@janakachathuranga/coding-best-practices-javascript-write-small-functions-7d2567bd6328)
3. Prefer [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) over `onclick` or `onanything`
4. There are two types of events you could use on the `input`s: [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) and [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). `input` will react on every keystroke, `check` will only react, if you blur the `input` element
5. I added a check for validity to the email field with [`checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method

   ```js
   {
     const btn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
     const fname = document.getElementById("fname");
     const email = document.getElementById("email");
     deactivate()
     
     function activate() {
       btn.disabled = false;
     }
     
     function deactivate() {
       btn.disabled = true;
     }

     function check() {
       if (fname.value != '' && email.value != '' && email.checkValidity()) {
         activate()
       } else {
         deactivate()
       }
     }
     
     btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       alert('submit')
     })
     
     
     fname.addEventListener('input', check)
     email.addEventListener('input', check)
     
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <form>
     <input type="text" name="" id="fname">
     <input type="email" name="" id="email">
     <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Submit">
   </form>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I can imagine:

```js
myForm.oninput = () => {
  btn.disabled = fname.value == '' || email.value == '' || !email.checkValidity();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="" id="fname">
  <input type="email" name="" id="email">
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Personally, I prefer to use regex to check the e-mail, instead of `checkValidity()`. Something like this:

```
/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/.test(email.value);
```